# Runnning SpriteKit processes in background threads to improve CPU usage

Tags: swift, multithreading, sprite-kit, background-process

I'm building my first game with Swift and SpriteKit and I've been having many problems with CPU use and consequently battery life. I wanted to know if it was common practice to run certain tasks, like instantiating bad guys, in background threads; and if so how I would go about implementing that?

Comment: Are you using SKShapeNode?

Comment: Change your question to what is causing lag, and post some code.  People will be able to help you out as to why you are lagging.  Otherwise we can be playing guessing games till swift 4 comes out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is your first game, you may not want to go crazy with multiple threads unless you really know what you are doing. Be aware that manipulating `SKNode`s must be done on the same thread that `SKView(Private) _update:` is run on. This is the same thread that `runAction` blocks are run on. If you don't you'll crash. In a SpriteKit game I was working on, I was multi-threaded and was not using `SKAction` or `runAction` for any updating. I had to eventually add `runAction` for tree management. I'm currently in the process of re-writing this in OpenGL because of this.

There are certain tasks which make sense to offload, like loading files or even network calls. You should be using GCD for those types of things. Keep in mind that multi-threading does not reduce CPU time as you are imagining.

Odds are your code is doing something bad which is causing you to eat CPU time. Even if you multi-thread, you will end up with the same high CPU but with the problem of a more difficult time debugging. Note I'm not saying its impossible.

Spend the time and figure out really why your CPU usage is high. Based on your other threads, you are not doing a lot.

As an experiment take that spaceship example and run it on your device. Keep adding ships and see what it does to the CPU. Find out how many you have to add before CPU and FPS degrade. Compare that to your game, keeping in mind that the spaceship example is just a simple demo.

Comment: I actually was playing with that demo the other day-- to my surprise I was able to add around 200 ships without any lag and only ~20% CPU use. I know it may seem like I've been almost flippant with your comments, but trust me I really appreciate them and have been working pretty much every day to figure out what I'm doing wrong, implementing advice along the way. So far I've managed to improve a couple things in my ship class but the overall trend to 100% CPU remains the same. It seems to be stemming from instantiation, excessive calls in update, and some other ship functionality.

Comment: You can manipulate SKNodes off the main thread, providing that they are not doing anything on the main thread, basically if they are not a part of the scene tree,

Comment: Yep, I generalized on this to keep it simple. I tend to find it easier to forget this and then try and sneak in an `addChild` on something that happens to be in the scene hierarchy. I should also point out it may not always crash. The crash will occur if it happens that the timing corresponds with the render cycle.

Comment: @Sam, no worries. Since this is your first game, many of the details can be overwhelming. It's easy to try and move on too soon and hope the newer shiny method will fix your problems. Many of these methods become Pandora's Box, because they just lead to newer more complicated issues which are worsened by not necessarily fully grasping the new method or what the existing code is doing. I recommend you separate your issues (eg. instantiation, update, other) and with each issue break it down into simpler issues/components you can disable then re-enable. This is a valuable skill to master.

Comment: @MobileBen Thanks a lot, I feel like this is the trap I've sort of fallen into. I spent this afternoon building it from scratch and monitoring the CPU on each added subsection, and I found that ~20-30% of CPU is from `touchesMoved`- which makes sense b/c this is being continually called as the users finger has to always be down to move the ship. However, when I remove  the two lines:

Comment: `let touchStartPoint:CGPoint = startingTouches[touch as! UITouch]!`
`if(controlBase.frame.contains(touchStartPoint)){
     controlStick.position = location
 }`                                                                                                                      under:                                                                                                     `override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch : AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)`                   I only hit ~4%??

Comment: Okay it sounds like you made some good progress. And congrats, you took a big step forward in being willing to re-write a bunch of code. Regarding your issue, I would suggest a few things to try. First, have the `if` code do nothing. So in other words, comment out `controlStick.position = location`.  Also make the body of your `for` loop in `touchesMoved` be also commented out. This is essentially disabling things one by one. How is `startingTouches` constructed? Your most intensive item should really be the `contains`. That will be dependent upon the nodes.

Comment: BTW, you can always try and copy this into spaceships and see what happens there ;)